# CSS flash effect over an image

Tags: css

Is it possible to create that "flash" like this on image, only using CSS?

I tried `-webkit-filter` but this doesn't look good.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "flash effect"?

Comment: A wild guess but you might be able to do it by defining a map over the image and applying CSS 3 gradient effect to the desired area. But of course you might as well open up photoshop and do it in like 10 seconds

Comment: As Rounin has asked, can you please explain in a little greater detail what you mean by "flash".

Comment: Please post the codes you have so far

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```css
div {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 160px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  content: " ";
  top: calc(50% - 40px);
  left: calc(50% - 80px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```